# How to run one action regardless of forked paths

Tags: power-automate

Is it possible to run one Create Item action regardless of which path the preceding actions take?

The image below shows what I'm trying to accomplish.  Basically, the 'Last Substring of Rank'action turns a variable into an integer. If it fails, it takes the left fork. If it succeeds, it takes the right.  Both forks then get an item and sets the same variable.  I then want that variable passed to the 'Create Item' action.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this. I just needed to add 'IsSkipped' to the Configure After Run for each fork.